# Bcrypt Elastic beanstalk nodejs deploy

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bcrypt, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my nodejs backend with codeship to elastic beanstalk. But everytime I get the following error:

```
bcrypt@1.0.3 install /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '../'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp:15:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

npm ERR! Linux 4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/npm" "--production" "rebuild"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? been trying to fix it for couple days now, help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can see the github issue thread - https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/509. It seems that a lot of people are having the same problem as you.

Answer (score 9):

Try to use `bcrypt.js` module instead of `bcrypt` which is an update/latest npm module. 
Run `npm install bcryptjs`
and then `npm install`

Comment: It should be npm install bcryptjs. Not npm install bcrypt.js

Answer (score 5):

First make sure you are not uploading the node modules folder and that the npm install command is working on the instance.

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions

This problem is related to node-pre-gyp. A dependency of bcrypt.

For AWS Elastic Beanstalk When deploying to Elastic Beanstalk running Node 8.x, node-gyp doesn't have sufficient permissions to write to the tmp directory. bcrypt won't install and the application deployment will fail.

A workaround is to add a .npmrc file to the root of your project that will force node-gyp to run as root and allow the installation to complete. File contents for .npmrc:

```
# Force npm to run node-gyp also as root, preventing permission denied errors in AWS with npm@5 or @6
unsafe-perm=true
```

Another alternative (Perhaps the more right way) is to make .ebextensions file with code:

.ebextensions:00_change_npm_permissions.config:

```
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/00_set_tmp_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      chown -R nodejs:nodejs /tmp/.npm
```

This will give you sufficient access to run node-gyp

Comment: I am a bit flabbergasted as to how the other answers got more upvotes as it doesn't really apply to Elastic Beanstalk deployment flows. @Sai Kassam's answer is actually the closest thing to the correct answer and using a `.npmrc` file would solve this issue and allow the deployment flow for EBS to actually install bcrypt. @bytesbase, it may be worth exploring this as a solution to your problem and if it works, mark @sai Kassam's answer as the correct answer so others that face the exact same issue can benefit from it.

Answer (score 4):

See this GitHub comment: https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/509#issuecomment-313693838

TL;DR: as a workaround run `npm install bcrypt` before running `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

I created a `.npmrc` file with:

```
unsafe-perm=true
```

That seemed to have done it.

Comment: This is the same answer as above and doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 0):

Add `bcryptjs` dependency in your `package.json` and then `npm install` should work with all the dependencies.